# Xbox controller disconnects immeditely on pc

Tags: pc, controllers

I have had this problem off and on and I'm not sure what is causing it.

The batteries are full (I have rechargable batteries) but when I put on the controller (xbox one) it connects briefly to the pc via the wireless dongle and then immediately disconnects.

I have tried multiple things to fix this problem:

- Updating the controller drivers
- Updating/reinstalling the directx drivers (this sometimes helps)
- Removing the drivers for the wireless dongle (again sometimes helps)
- Restarting my pc (another instance that sometimes helps)

All of the above are pretty impractical when it comes to just wanting to play a game.

From some use and experimentation it seems to happen because the controller disconnects unexpectedly, what is actually happening I have no idea.

Also this has been going on for for more than a year at least and I am on windows 11 with the latest insider build (this could be a problem but this started on windows 10)

PC Spec:

- CPU: Ryzen 9 5950X
- GPU: GALAX RTX 3080TI
- OS Version: Windows 11, Build: 22623.1245

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to connect the controller via a cable. Find the controller in the Device Manager and uninstall it; the controller should now turn off.

After this, try and reconnect wirelessly, and it should reconnect without a problem.